# why does w3schools.org route to my localhost?

Tags: xampp

I have xampp set up But I am damn sure that I don't have a w3schools.org in any of my projects . . . what kind of witchcraft is this ?

This is what I get in my browser

[image]

Comment: Do you have `w3schools.org` in your hosts file (maybe as some sort of ad blocking measure)?

Comment: where is hosts file ?

Comment: Assuming you're running Windows, it's in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29#Location_in_the_file_system). BTW, this is just one of a number of possibilities for what you're seeing; others include something weird in your DNS or proxy setup.

Comment: I  don't have w3schools.org in my hosts file . . .